# C# OpenCL GPU implementation for double array math

Tags: c#, .net, opencl, gpu

How can I make the for loop of this function to use the GPU with OpenCL?

```
    public static double[] Calculate(double[] num, int period)
    {          
        var final = new double[num.Length];
        double sum = num[0];
        double coeff = 2.0 / (1.0 + period);

        for (int i = 0; i < num.Length; i++)
        {
            sum += coeff * (num[i] - sum);
            final[i] = sum;
        }

        return final;
    }
```

Comment: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1116907/How-to-Use-Your-GPU-in-NET

Comment: Thanks! I have read that, but I don't get it. I don't understand the kernel and global functions

Comment: tbh, you don't really need to understand them. Your function is almost exactly like the one in the example. Just make sure you pass the parameters in the correct order and it should work. I don't have the proper environment set up to test.

Comment: why is this question receiving down votes? sounds like a valid question from a newbie.  and why is it newbie questions are always frowned upon here?

Comment: what are your values for num and period?

Comment: usually it's fixed, 14 or 20, but the array is big, over 100k values

Comment: Why would you use the GPU for this? You can do this on the CPU far faster than the GPU as it's not an easily parallelizable problem - the first element in the array affects the last value.

Comment: on CPU it takes a few hours until it calculates all the values many times, the GPU should be much more faster

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your problem as written does not fit well with something that would work on a GPU. You cannot parallelize (in a way that improves performance) the operation on a single array because the value of the nth element depends on elements 1 to n. However, you can utilize the GPU to process multiple arrays, where each GPU core operates on a separate array.

The full code for the solution is at the end of the answer, but the results of the test, to calculate on 10,000 arrays each of which has 10,000 elements, generates the following (on a GTX1080M and an i7 7700k with 32GB RAM):

```
Task Generating Data: 1096.4583ms
Task CPU Single Thread: 596.2624ms
Task CPU Parallel: 179.1717ms
GPU CPU->GPU: 89ms
GPU Execute: 86ms
GPU GPU->CPU: 29ms
Task Running GPU: 921.4781ms
Finished
```

In this test, we measure the speed at which we can generate results into a managed C# array using the CPU with one thread, the CPU with all threads, and finally the GPU using all cores. **We validate that the results from each test are identical, using the function AreTheSame.**

The fastest time is processing the arrays on the CPU using all threads (Task CPU Parallel: 179ms).

The GPU is actually the slowest (Task Running GPU: 922ms), but this is because of the time taken to reformat the C# arrays in a way that they can be transferred onto the GPU.

If this bottleneck were removed (which is quite possible, depending on your use case), the GPU could potentially be the fastest. If the data were already formatted in a manner that can be immediately be transferred onto the GPU, the total processing time for the GPU would be 204ms (CPU->GPU: 89ms + Execute: 86ms + GPU->CPU: 29 ms = 204ms). This is still slower than the parallel CPU option, but on a different sort of data set, it might be faster.

To get the data back from the GPU (the most important part of actually using the GPU), we use the function ComputeCommandQueue.Read. This transfers the altered array on the GPU back to the CPU.

To run the following code, reference the Cloo Nuget Package (I used 0.9.1). And make sure to compile on x64 (you will need the memory). You may need to update your graphics card driver too if it fails to find an OpenCL device.

```
class Program
{
    static string CalculateKernel
    {
        get
        {
            return @"
            kernel void Calc(global int* offsets, global int* lengths, global double* doubles, double periodFactor) 
            {
                int id = get_global_id(0);
                int start = offsets[id];
                int length = lengths[id];
                int end = start + length;
                double sum = doubles[start];

                for(int i = start; i < end; i++)
                {
                    sum = sum + periodFactor * ( doubles[i] - sum );
                    doubles[i] = sum;
                }
            }";
        }
    }

    public static double[] Calculate(double[] num, int period)
    {
        var final = new double[num.Length];
        double sum = num[0];
        double coeff = 2.0 / (1.0 + period);

        for (int i = 0; i < num.Length; i++)
        {
            sum += coeff * (num[i] - sum);
            final[i] = sum;
        }

        return final;
    }


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        int maxElements = 10000;
        int numArrays = 10000;
        int computeCores = 2048;

        double[][] sets = new double[numArrays][];

        using (Timer("Generating Data"))
        {
            Random elementRand = new Random(1);
            for (int i = 0; i < numArrays; i++)
            {
                sets[i] = GetRandomDoubles(elementRand.Next((int)(maxElements * 0.9), maxElements), randomSeed: i);
            }
        }

        int period = 14;

        double[][] singleResults;
        using (Timer("CPU Single Thread"))
        {
            singleResults = CalculateCPU(sets, period);
        }

        double[][] parallelResults;
        using (Timer("CPU Parallel"))
        {
            parallelResults = CalculateCPUParallel(sets, period);
        }

        if (!AreTheSame(singleResults, parallelResults)) throw new Exception();

        double[][] gpuResults;
        using (Timer("Running GPU"))
        {
            gpuResults = CalculateGPU(computeCores, sets, period);
        }

        if (!AreTheSame(singleResults, gpuResults)) throw new Exception();


        Console.WriteLine("Finished");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public static bool AreTheSame(double[][] a1, double[][] a2)
    {
        if (a1.Length != a2.Length) return false;
        for (int i = 0; i < a1.Length; i++)
        {
            var ar1 = a1[i];
            var ar2 = a2[i];
            if (ar1.Length != ar2.Length) return false;
            for (int j = 0; j < ar1.Length; j++)
                if (Math.Abs(ar1[j] - ar2[j]) > 0.0000001) return false;

        }
        return true;
    }

    public static double[][] CalculateGPU(int partitionSize, double[][] sets, int period)
    {
        ComputeContextPropertyList cpl = new ComputeContextPropertyList(ComputePlatform.Platforms[0]);
        ComputeContext context = new ComputeContext(ComputeDeviceTypes.Gpu, cpl, null, IntPtr.Zero);


        ComputeProgram program = new ComputeProgram(context, new string[] { CalculateKernel });
        program.Build(null, null, null, IntPtr.Zero);

        ComputeCommandQueue commands = new ComputeCommandQueue(context, context.Devices[0], ComputeCommandQueueFlags.None);

        ComputeEventList events = new ComputeEventList();

        ComputeKernel kernel = program.CreateKernel("Calc");


        double[][] results = new double[sets.Length][];

        double periodFactor = 2d / (1d + period);

        Stopwatch sendStopWatch = new Stopwatch();
        Stopwatch executeStopWatch = new Stopwatch();
        Stopwatch recieveStopWatch = new Stopwatch();


        int offset = 0;
        while (true)
        {
            int first = offset;
            int last = Math.Min(offset + partitionSize, sets.Length);
            int length = last - first;

            var merged = Merge(sets, first, length);

            sendStopWatch.Start();

            ComputeBuffer<int> offsetBuffer = new ComputeBuffer<int>(
                context,
                ComputeMemoryFlags.ReadWrite | ComputeMemoryFlags.UseHostPointer,
                merged.Offsets);

            ComputeBuffer<int> lengthsBuffer = new ComputeBuffer<int>(
                context,
                ComputeMemoryFlags.ReadWrite | ComputeMemoryFlags.UseHostPointer,
                merged.Lengths);

            ComputeBuffer<double> doublesBuffer = new ComputeBuffer<double>(
                context,
                ComputeMemoryFlags.ReadWrite | ComputeMemoryFlags.UseHostPointer,
                merged.Doubles);



            kernel.SetMemoryArgument(0, offsetBuffer);
            kernel.SetMemoryArgument(1, lengthsBuffer);
            kernel.SetMemoryArgument(2, doublesBuffer);
            kernel.SetValueArgument(3, periodFactor);

            sendStopWatch.Stop();

            executeStopWatch.Start();

            commands.Execute(kernel, null, new long[] { merged.Lengths.Length }, null, events);

            executeStopWatch.Stop();

            using (var pin = Pinned(merged.Doubles))
            {
                recieveStopWatch.Start();
                commands.Read(doublesBuffer, false, 0, merged.Doubles.Length, pin.Address, events);
                commands.Finish();
                recieveStopWatch.Stop();
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < merged.Lengths.Length; i++)
            {
                int len = merged.Lengths[i];
                int off = merged.Offsets[i];

                var res = new double[len];
                Array.Copy(merged.Doubles,off,res,0,len);

                results[first + i] = res;
            }


            offset += partitionSize;
            if (offset >= sets.Length) break;
        }

        Console.WriteLine("GPU CPU->GPU: " + recieveStopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds + "ms");
        Console.WriteLine("GPU Execute: " + executeStopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds + "ms");
        Console.WriteLine("GPU GPU->CPU: " + sendStopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds + "ms");


        return results;
    }

    public static PinnedHandle Pinned(object obj) => new PinnedHandle(obj);
    public class PinnedHandle : IDisposable
    {
        public IntPtr Address => handle.AddrOfPinnedObject();
        private GCHandle handle;
        public PinnedHandle(object val)
        {
            handle = GCHandle.Alloc(val, GCHandleType.Pinned);
        }
        public void Dispose()
        {
            handle.Free();
        }
    }

    public class MergedResults
    {
        public double[] Doubles { get; set; }
        public int[] Lengths { get; set; }
        public int[] Offsets { get; set; }
    }



    public static MergedResults Merge(double[][] sets, int offset, int length)
    {
        List<int> lengths = new List<int>(length);
        List<int> offsets = new List<int>(length);

        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            var arr = sets[i + offset];
            lengths.Add(arr.Length);
        }
        var totalLength = lengths.Sum();

        double[] doubles = new double[totalLength];
        int dataOffset = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            var arr = sets[i + offset];
            Array.Copy(arr, 0, doubles, dataOffset, arr.Length);
            offsets.Add(dataOffset);
            dataOffset += arr.Length;
        }

        return new MergedResults()
        {
            Doubles = doubles,
            Lengths = lengths.ToArray(),
            Offsets = offsets.ToArray(),
        };
    }


    public static IDisposable Timer(string name)
    {
        return new SWTimer(name);
    }

    public class SWTimer : IDisposable
    {
        private Stopwatch _sw;
        private string _name;
        public SWTimer(string name)
        {
            _name = name;
            _sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        }
        public void Dispose()
        {
            _sw.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("Task " + _name + ": " + _sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds + "ms");
        }

    }

    public static double[][] CalculateCPU(double[][] arrays, int period)
    {
        double[][] results = new double[arrays.Length][];
        for (var index = 0; index < arrays.Length; index++)
        {
            var arr = arrays[index];
            results[index] = Calculate(arr, period);
        }
        return results;
    }

    public static double[][] CalculateCPUParallel(double[][] arrays, int period)
    {
        double[][] results = new double[arrays.Length][];
        Parallel.For(0, arrays.Length, i =>
         {
             var arr = arrays[i];
             results[i] = Calculate(arr, period);
         });
        return results;
    }


    static double[] GetRandomDoubles(int num, int randomSeed)
    {
        Random r = new Random(randomSeed);
        var res = new double[num];
        for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
            res[i] = r.NextDouble() * 0.9 + 0.05;
        return res;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's taking hours, because it's doing this calculation of 100k values 2 million times, with different values. I have profiled the performance of the app and the botleneck is this function where it spends 60% of the time.

Comment: When it's going 2M times, are all the arrays of equal length? What is the data source for the arrays - can you batch them 1000 at a time?

Comment: The arrays are not equal, because it takes days of data and calculates daily prices using different times (by 5 minutes, 30 minutes, 1 hour)

Comment: I already made this function to run on multiple CPU threads with Tasks and it's more than 5 times faster on my i7 6700K CPU than running it on a single thread.  You are doing something wrong, it can't be faster on a single thread than multiple threads which fills all the CPU cores.

Comment: It's not faster on single thread - it's 5x faster on multiple threads. 5 seconds to process on single, 1s to process on multiple...

Comment: And then why do you believe that by using the CPU + GPU will not be faster?

Comment: Because 1) There's a large overhead you incur when reformatting data to go onto the GPU; 2) You incur a delay when data needs to be transferred from the CPU to the GPU, and back again; 3) GPUs are better for computational operations with relatively low memory transfer requirements, but what you have is a memory intensive calculation with low computational requirements.

Comment: but GPU's have faster memory, they use DDR5, can you modify your sample also to test the GPU? So I can choose your answer. I still believe that by using both the CPU + GPU I will get at least 3-4 times more performance using my AMD R9 290x GPU

Comment: If this code references Nuget Package Cloo and OpenCLLib which I referenced then it should not work as there is not mechanism to return anything from a function.  How was your code tested?

Comment: Thanks! Great Answer! What is the difference between GPU Execute and Task Running GPU? I will test it out.

Comment: @Aaron.S and MarioM - I edited the answer to answer your questions.

Comment: again, was this code actually tested?  you should receive an exception stating your doubles array cannot be modified.  how did you work around that with your existing code?

Comment: @Aaron.S Yes it was tested, and working on my hardware described in the answer. If it's not working on your hardware, can you provide the exact exception message, so I can see the issue? (Yes, you can edit the arrays on the graphics card - the edited array can be read back used the function as described, as long as the relevant ComputeBuffer uses the ComputeMemoryFlags.ReadWrite or Write flag.)

Answer (score 5):

as commenter Cory stated refer to this link for setup.

[How to use your GPU in .NET](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:kXp2OT5juFIJ:https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1116907/How-to-Use-Your-GPU-in-NET%20&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=uk)

Here is how you would use this project:

1. Add the Nuget Package Cloo
2. Add reference to OpenCLlib.dll
3. Download [OpenCLLib.zip](https://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/1116907/OpenCLLib.zip)
4. Add using OpenCL

   ```
   static void Main(string[] args)
   {
       int[] Primes = { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 };
       EasyCL cl = new EasyCL();
       cl.Accelerator = AcceleratorDevice.GPU;
       cl.LoadKernel(IsPrime);
       cl.Invoke("GetIfPrime", 0, Primes.Length, Primes, 1.0);
   }

   static string IsPrime
   {
       get
       {
           return @"
           kernel void GetIfPrime(global int* num, int period)
           {
               int index = get_global_id(0);

               int sum = (2.0 / (1.0 + period)) * (num[index] - num[0]);
               printf("" %d \n"",sum);
           }";
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: I know this is not exactly what you need but its a start?

Comment: the problem is it returns a string and I need a double array, if I have to convert from string back to double array I did nothing by making this function to use the GPU, because the double array is very big, also the calculation is not good, there is no more for loop.

Comment: the invoke command is executed the same number of times as the length of Primes is.  thus why Primes.Length is sent as a parameter.  that is the looping mechanism.  as for the string being returned you are going to need to do the extra work to figure out that part.  I already did most of the work for you.

Comment: BUT let me see if I can further adjust my answer to meet your needs.  give me some valid data for your parameters and what the expected outcome should be, please

Comment: period=14, num [] = 0.241, 0.220, 0.532, 0.455, 0.778, 0.243, 0.882, 0.442, 0.990, 0.124, 0.550, 0.552, 0.500, 0.995, 0.444, 0.440, 0.700, 0.720, 0.744, 0.550, 0.850, 0.200, 0.444, 0.560

Answer (score 2):

```
    for (int i = 0; i < num.Length; i++)
    {
        sum += coeff * (num[i] - sum);
        final[i] = sum;
    }
```

means first element is multiplied by coeff 1 time and subtracted from 2nd element. First element also multiplied by square of coeff and this time added to 3rd element. Then first element multiplied by cube of coeff and subtracted from 4th element.

This is going like this:

```
-e0*c*c*c + e1*c*c - e2*c = f3
e0*c*c*c*c - e1*c*c*c + e2*c*c - e3*c = f4
-e0*c*c*c*c*c + e1*c*c*c*c - e2*c*c*c + e3*c*c - e4*c =f5
```

For all elements, scan through for all smaller id elements and compute this:

if difference of id values(lets call it k) of elements is odd, take subtraction, if not then take addition. Before addition or subtraction, multiply that value by k-th power of coeff. Lastly, multiply the current num value by coefficient and add it to current cell. Current cell value is final(i).

This is O(N*N) and looks like an all-pairs compute kernel. An example using an open-source C# OpenCL project:

```
ClNumberCruncher cruncher = new ClNumberCruncher(ClPlatforms.all().gpus(), @"
    __kernel void foo(__global double * num, __global double * final, __global int *parameters)
    {
        int threadId           = get_global_id(0);
        int period             = parameters[0];
        double coeff           = 2.0 / (1.0 + period);    
        double sumOfElements   = 0.0;
        for(int i=0;i<threadId;i++)
        {
            // negativity of coeff is to select addition or subtraction for different powers of coeff
            double powKofCoeff =  pow(-coeff,threadId-i);
            sumOfElements     +=  powKofCoeff * num[i];                     
        }
        final[threadId]        =  sumOfElements + num[threadId] * coeff;
    }
");
cruncher.performanceFeed = true; // getting benchmark feedback on console
double[] numArray = new double[10000];
double[] finalArray = new double[10000];
int[] parameters = new int[10];
int period = 15;
parameters[0] = period;
ClArray<double> numGpuArray = numArray;
numGpuArray.readOnly = true; // gpus read this from host
ClArray<double> finalGpuArray = finalArray; // finalArray will have results
finalGpuArray.writeOnly = true; // gpus write this to host
ClArray<int> parametersGpu = parameters;
parametersGpu.readOnly = true;

// calculate kernels with exact same ordering of parameters
// num(double),final(double),parameters(int)
// finalGpuArray points to __global double * final
numGpuArray.nextParam(finalGpuArray, parametersGpu).compute(cruncher, 1, "foo", 10000, 100);

// first compute always lags because of compiling the kernel so here are repeated computes to get actual performance
numGpuArray.nextParam(finalGpuArray, parametersGpu).compute(cruncher, 1, "foo", 10000, 100);
numGpuArray.nextParam(finalGpuArray, parametersGpu).compute(cruncher, 1, "foo", 10000, 100);
```

Results are on `finalArray` array for 10000 elements, using 100 workitems per workitem-group.

GPGPU part takes 82ms on a rx550 gpu which has very low ratio of 64bit-to-32bit compute performance(because consumer gaming cards are not good at double precision for new series). An Nvidia Tesla or an Amd Vega would easily compute this kernel without crippled performance. Fx8150(8 cores) completes in 683ms. If you need to specifically select only an integrated-GPU and its CPU, you can use

`ClPlatforms.all().gpus().devicesWithHostMemorySharing() + ClPlatforms.all().cpus()` when creating `ClNumberCruncher` instance.

binaries of api:

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1181213/Easy-OpenCL-Multiple-Device-Load-Balancing-and-Pip

or source code to compile on your pc:

https://github.com/tugrul512bit/Cekirdekler

if you have multiple gpus, it uses them without any extra code. Including a cpu to the computations would pull gpu effectiveness down in this sample for first iteration (repeatations complete in 76ms with cpu+gpu) so its better to use 2-3 GPU instead of CPU+GPU.

---

I didn't check numerical stability(you should use Kahan-Summation when adding millions or more values into same variable but I didn't use it for readability and don't have an idea about if 64-bit values need this too like 32-bit ones) or any value correctness, you should do it. Also foo kernel is not optimized. It makes %50 of core times idle so it should be better scheduled like this:

```
thread-0: compute element 0 and element N-1
thread-1: compute element 1 and element N-2
thread-m: compute element N/2-1 and element N/2
```

so all workitems get similar amount of work. On top of this, using 100 for workgroup size is not optimal. It should be something like 128,256,512 or 1024(for Nvidia) but this means array size should also be an integer multiple of this too. Then it would need extra control logic in the kernel to not go out of array borders. For even more performance, for loop could have multiple partial sums to do a "loop unrolling".

Comment: The performance of this on 1 GPU core (allocated to the last element, and writing as it goes) or 10000 GPU cores as you've written would be the same.... You'd always just be waiting on the single core for the last element to finish. There's no point in parallelizing it this way...

Comment: You are right about the dependence of calculations. A single cpu core would finish at 10000 cycles which shouldnt be more than a millisecond. This is just a parallelized version. I also informed about being `O(N*N)` in the answer. But again, this is a parallel version as been asked and every final element is independently computed so that he doesnt need another element if he ever asks for Jth element.

Comment: CPU is idle while GPU is computing this so CPU can work on other tasks at the same time which means a little more work but of course wasted electricity energy.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, very elaborate. it was very hard to choose the best answer between your answer and MineR

Comment: I tried to find a way for a "reduction" but  couldn't achieve. Even reduction's O(Log(N)*N) is still slower than a simple single core O(N) addition so I just made some embarrrassingly parallel version with scalability and nothing more :)